# ElementClickInterceptedException. I am getting this error while scraping data for airline reviews on the website "Airline quality" using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

Website Url : [British Airways Reviews](https://www.airlinequality.com/airline-reviews/british-airways/?sortby=post_date%3ADesc&pagesize=100)

```
rating_title = []
for i in range(35):
    print("Scraping ", i+1)
    titles = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//h2[@class='text_header']")
    for title in titles:
        rating_title.append(title.text)
    next_button = browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text(">>")
    next_button.click()
    sleep(5)
```

[Notebook Cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMcPT.png)

I wrote this code to get reviews, firstly it was running fine but then I don't know what happened. It started giving this error(ElementClickInterceptedException).
Whenever you get to the second page there is an ad pop-up, could that be the reason for this error?(Most Probably I'm wrong about this)

P.S. Edit:

```
rating_title = []
for i in range(35):
    print("Scraping ", i+1)
    titles = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//h2[@class='text_header']")
    for title in titles:
        rating_title.append(title.text)
    next_button = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, ">>")))
    next_button.click()
```

I updated the code to this, still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Root cause for `ElementClickInterceptedException`:** Next button(`>>`) was overlapped by the below ad pop-up.

[image]

**Soution:** You need to scroll down to the extreme bottom of the page, Next button(`>>`) will be visible clearly and doesn't get overlapped.

**Here is the full working code:**

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.airlinequality.com/airline-reviews/british-airways/?sortby=post_date%3ADesc&pagesize=100")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
rating_title = []
for i in range(35):
    print("Scraping ", i+1)
    titles = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//h2[@class='text_header']")))
    for title in titles:
        rating_title.append(title.text)
    # Below line scrolls down to the bottom of the page, this line is to avoid ElementClickIntercepted exception due to the ad popup
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    next_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, ">>")))
    next_button.click()
    wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "aswift_7")))
    # below if-else condition is to handle the intermittent ad popup which appears after clicking Next_button ">>"
    if (len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//iframe[@title='Advertisement']")) >= 1):
        wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@title='Advertisement']")))
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Close']"))).click()
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        time.sleep(1)

    driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

**Console Output:**

```
Scraping  1
Scraping  2
Scraping  3
Scraping  4
Scraping  5
Scraping  6
Scraping  7
Scraping  8
Scraping  9
Scraping  10
Scraping  11
Scraping  12
Scraping  13
Scraping  14
Scraping  15
Scraping  16
Scraping  17
Scraping  18
Scraping  19
Scraping  20
Scraping  21
Scraping  22
Scraping  23
Scraping  24
Scraping  25
Scraping  26
Scraping  27
Scraping  28
Scraping  29
Scraping  30
Scraping  31
Scraping  32
Scraping  33
Scraping  34
Scraping  35

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Yeah I tried this code, although it worked but now it is showing another error

Comment: '''
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 14
     12 if (len(browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//iframe[@title='Advertisement']")) >= 1):
     13     wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@title='Advertisement']")))
---> 14     wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Close']"))).click()
     15     time.sleep(1)
'''

Comment: I'm sorry about the bad formatting, I am new to stack overflow and still getting used to it.

Comment: I just ran the same code with no issues. Are you getting the error all the time? Or is it a one-off? Are you using the same code which is in this answer?

Comment: I am using the same code, and Now I used it with try and except block, now it is running fine. Thank you

Comment: @DhruvYadav- Glad it worked. Accept the answer if it has resolved your issue so that it's not left un answered.

Comment: I am getting another error while extraction different tags 

Comment: I suggest ask a new question with the exact issue, that way you get answers from wider community.